# set input values in array and randomize content to display

Tags: javascript, arrays, randomized-algorithm

I can't seem to find any solutions.
I want to create a form that collects 4 nicknames after submit a form and then displays them all randomly in html code using javascript

My 4 input values are now in an array.
I have to display them randomly in two different teams.

I'm trying to get a random index, and as long as it's different from the ones already assigned to avoid one person being on both teams.
This code works, but sometimes, one player is assigned to 2 teams. Then, the randomizer doesn't work... Do you have an idea ?

```
function getRandomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

function getData() {

    let joueur1     = document.querySelector("#player1").value;
    let joueur2     = document.querySelector("#player2").value;
    let joueur3     = document.querySelector("#player3").value;
    let joueur4     = document.querySelector("#player4").value;

    playerList.push(player1.value);
    playerList.push(player2.value);
    playerList.push(player3.value);
    playerList.push(player4.value);

        randomNumber1           = getRandomNumber(playerList.length);
        last1 += randomNumber1;
        random1.textContent     = playerList[randomNumber1];
        do {
          randomNumber2         = getRandomNumber(playerList.length);
        } while (randomNumber2  == last1 && last4 && last3);
        last2 += randomNumber2        
        random2.textContent     = playerList[randomNumber2];

        do {
          randomNumber3         = getRandomNumber(playerList.length);
        } while (randomNumber3  == last1 && last2 && last4);
        last3 += randomNumber3
        random3.textContent   = playerList[randomNumber3];

        do {
          randomNumber4         = getRandomNumber(playerList.length);
        }while (randomNumber4   == last1 && last2 && last3)
        random4.textContent     = playerList[randomNumber4];
        last4 += randomNumber4
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Once an element is targeted, you need to read the `value` property: `let joueur1 = document.querySelector("#player1").value` -- But is the `form` submitted? -- Do you have any event handler where to put this logic? -- Where is the random teams supposed to show?

Comment: Ok, i can now target the value at the submit 


```
function getData() {

    let joueur1     = document.querySelector("#player1").value;
    let joueur2     = document.querySelector("#player2").value;
    let joueur3     = document.querySelector("#player3").value;
    let joueur4     = document.querySelector("#player4").value;
    console.log(joueur1)
}
```
Thanks for your help. I need now to get them in an array and to randomly display in 2 different team for this team generator. And innerHTML them in 4 "P" elements

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of getting a random item from your array

Here you add your items into array

```
let joueur1     = document.querySelector("#player1").value;
let joueur2     = document.querySelector("#player2").value;
let joueur3     = document.querySelector("#player3").value;
let joueur4     = document.querySelector("#player4").value;
let playerList=[];
playerList.push(joueur1);
playerList.push(joueur2);
playerList.push(joueur3);
playerList.push(joueur4);
```

Then, Here is how you can get randomized content

```
let randomPlayer = playerList[Math.floor(Math.random() * playerList.length)];
```

`Math.random()` will never be 1. The largest index is always one less than the length of the array

Comment: Thanks You ! 
But it may assign the same number twice ?

Comment: It has a low probability. As your array gets bigger the probability of reassigning will decrease

Comment: If this answer helped you don't forget to accept it as an accepted answer